# Performance creating table in function for join

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I'm comparing two queries in SQL Server and trying to determine if one is actually much more efficient than the other. I'm using the AdventureWorks2016 sample database from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ssms

In one query I am using a function that creates a table with an index that is used in the join. The second query is using a sub-query to replace the function.

```sql
create function departmentSummary()
  returns @tmp Table (
  DepartmentID int,
  NumEmployees int,
  primary key (DepartmentID)
)
as
begin
  insert into @tmp
  select DepartmentID, count(*)
  from [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
  where EndDate is null
  group by DepartmentID;
  return
end;
go;

select a.*, b.NumEmployees
from [HumanResources].[Department] as a
join dbo.departmentSummary() as b on a.DepartmentID = b.DepartmentID;

select a.*, b.NumEmployees
from [HumanResources].[Department] as a
join (
  select DepartmentID, count(*) NumEmployees
  from [HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]
  where EndDate is null
  group by DepartmentID
) as b on a.DepartmentID = b.DepartmentID;
```

[image: execution plan for queries]

The execution plan shows that the query using the function has much less cost. I'm wondering if the all the work the function did is actually being included in the cost or is the index for the join making that much impact.

Comment: As you are interested in best practices, it's best practice to always list the columns you are inserting into, in an insert statement. Then you don't get caught out if the tables columns change.

Comment: As a side note, if the function was an inline TVF rather than a multi-statement one then you'd find they would both have identical query plans. `CREATE FUNCTION ... RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT ...` with no `BEGIN END`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exercise a lot of caution with comparing subtree costs.

This is [not a reliable way](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29650/3690) of comparing different queries for efficiency.

> They are not intended to be used to assess potential performance, even
> at a 'high level'. The model is an abstraction that happens to work
> reasonably well for the internal purposes it was designed for. The
> chances that estimated costs bear any sensible resemblance to real
> execution costs on your hardware and configuration is very small
> indeed.
>
> Choose other metrics to compare performance, based on whatever real
> issues are important to you.

Even within those parameters the TVF is not costed cheaper than the query without however. SSMS just doesn't show you the execution plan for the query that runs within the multi statement TVF itself and does the select from `[HumanResources].[EmployeeDepartmentHistory]` and insert to `@tmp`. Nor is this cost reflected in the costs of the "Table Valued Function" operator.

If it did show you this the full picture would look like the below - with the two statements for the query with the multistatement TVF totalling 60% of the batch cost.

The plan for the function is quite similar to the green highlighted part of the plan without. So they do much the same thing but the function has some additional overhead of needing to insert the grouped rows to a table variable rather than just getting on with the correlated seek against `Department` immediately.

[image]

BTW: for this answer I fired up profiler and used the "Showplan XML Statistics Profile" event to get the missing actual execution plan that SSMS does not show. The same would be possible in a less deprecated and better performing way by using XEvents to capture the execution plans.